# Web service API email send with attachement

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, webservices, attachment

I'd like to send an attachment (let's say an on-the-fly generated HTML document) with an HTML email I'm sending via the [Web Service API](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_an_email_via_the_web_service_api/).

I don't see anything called out in the docs for this, just how to do so with AMPScript via FTP/HTTP/Portfolio.

Is this possible?